# How to repeat SQL insertion until successful with pg-promise?

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql, promise, pg-promise

In my program I insert some data into a table and get back it's id and I need to ensure I enter that id into another table with a unique randomly generated string. But, in case the insertion fails for attempting to insert an already-existing random string, how could I repeat the insertion until it is successful?

I'm using `pg-promise` to talk to postgreSQL. I can run program like this that inserts the data into both tables given the random string doesn't already exists:

```
   db.none(
            `
            WITH insert_post AS
            (
                INSERT INTO table_one(text) VALUES('abcd123')
                RETURNING id
            )
            INSERT INTO table_two(id, randstr)
                    VALUES((SELECT id FROM insert_post), '${randStrFn()}')
            `
        )
    .then(() => console.log("Success"))
    .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

I'm unsure if there is any easy SQL/JS/pg-promise based solution that I could make use of.

Comment: just wondering - why you use random strings instead of ID/sequence/UUID?

Comment: Perhaps what you are trying to achieve is irrelevant to the library you are using. Sounds like you just need to append `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` to your `INSERT` query, or similar. Anyhow, it is an SQL-related question, not library-related.

Comment: @Lashane The random string will be an alias to id that front-end user will make use of.

Comment: @vitaly-t I can't seem to find a decent `ON CONFLICT DO NOTHING` explanation for a beginner. Reading [this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/E1YqZCW-0000e6-Od@gemulon.postgresql.org), I'm unsure how to make use of it so I can re-try insertion if it fails.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would encourage the author of the question to seek a pure-SQL solution to his problem, as in terms of performance it would be significantly more efficient than anything else.

But since the question was about how to re-run queries with [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise), I will provide an example, in addition to one already published, except without acquiring and releasing the connection for every attempt, plus proper data integrity.

```
db.tx(t => {
    // BEGIN;
    return t.one('INSERT INTO table_one(text) VALUES($1) RETURNING id', 'abcd123', a => +a.id)
        .then(id => {
            var f = attempts => t.none('INSERT INTO table_two(id, randstr) VALUES($1, randStrFn())', id)
                .catch(error => {
                    if (--attempts) {
                        return f(attempts); // try again
                    }
                    throw error; // give up
                });
            return f(3); // try up to 3 times
        });
})
    .then(data => {
        // COMMIT;
        // success, data = null
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ROLLBACK;
    });
```

Since you are trying to re-run a dependent query, you should not let the first query remain successful, if all your attempts with the second query fail, you should roll all the changes back, i.e. use a transaction - method [tx](http://vitaly-t.github.io/pg-promise/Database.html#.tx), as shown in the code.

This is why we split your `WITH` query inside the transaction, to ensure such an integrity.

**UPDATE**

Below is a better version of it though. Because errors inside the transaction need to be isolated, in order to avoid breaking the transaction stack, each attempt should be inside its own `SAVEPOINT`, which means using another transaction level:

```
db.tx(t => {
    // BEGIN;
    return t.one('INSERT INTO table_one(name) VALUES($1) RETURNING id', 'abcd123', a => +a.id)
        .then(id => {
            var f = attempts => t.tx(sp => {
                // SAVEPOINT level_1;
                return sp.none('INSERT INTO table_two(id, randstr) VALUES($1, randStrFn())', id);
            })
                .catch(error => {
                    // ROLLBACK TO SAVEPOINT level_1;
                    if (--attempts) {
                        return f(attempts); // try again
                    }
                    throw error; // give up
                });
            return f(3); // try up to 3 times
        });
})
    .then(data => {
        // 1) RELEASE SAVEPOINT level_1;
        // 2) COMMIT;
    })
    .catch(error => {
        // ROLLBACK;
    });
```

I would also suggest using [pg-monitor](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-monitor), so you can see and understand what is happening underneath, and what queries are being in fact executed.

---

P.S. I'm the author of [pg-promise](https://github.com/vitaly-t/pg-promise).

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer and making pg-promise library. Although it works as expected and rolls back when can't enter to second table after 3 tries, it seems to still run the last `then(success)`.

Comment: @RobertC.Holland I don't see how this is possible. I updated the answer several times since the original post, so make sure you've copied the latest example precisely, without skipping anything. It must not get into the final `.then`, no way! I'm guessing, you skipped one of the `return` somewhere - check it ;)

Comment: You were right, my bad, probably made some mistake while copying earlier. Thanks again for the help.

Comment: @RobertC.Holland You might want to switch to the updated version, it is better ;)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to put it into a method then re-call that in the catch:

```
const insertPost = (post, numRetries) => {
    return
       db.none(
                `
                WITH insert_post AS
                (
                    INSERT INTO table_one(text) VALUES('abcd123')
                    RETURNING id
                )
                INSERT INTO table_two(id, randstr)
                        VALUES((SELECT id FROM insert_post), '${randStrFn()}')
                `
            )
        .then(() => console.log("Success"))
        .catch(err => {
            console.log(err)
            if (numRetries < 3) {
              return self.insertPost(post, numRetries + 1);
            }
            throw err;
        });

}
```

Comment: This would be technically correct, but very inefficient. The author should seek a pure-SQL solution to his problem, if performance matters to him.

Comment: Did not state it would be the most efficient but the easiest way to handle it. Personally I would something different but with out more details of the issue I went with the easiest.

Comment: There is another horrific effect that will occur from trying to do it on the top-level of the database object, because it will try to allocate and release a connection for every query. It should be just one connection. I'm gonna publish a better example of it shortly... ;)

Comment: Oh I agree with you. I would not use this code "as is" due to the fact it has too many performance issues.